Why does LCAO determined based on ground state molecular structure also apply under thermal vibration?
Why does the linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO), which is determined based on the symmetry of a molecular in its ground state atomic structure, remains valid considering that the molecule is constantly vibrating?
As a molecule is constantly vibrating under different modes, its atomic structure at a specific time t can noticeably differ from the ground state atomic structure. In this case, the point group symmetry of the molecule at time t is reduced compared to that of the molecule in its ground state. As a result, in the spirit of finding LCAOs based on the point group symmetry of molecules, does it mean that the molecule at time t corresponds to another type of LCAOs that is different from the ground state LCAOs?
I understand that there might not be such a type of LCAOs, but I can't figure out why the LCAOs determined based on the ground state atomic structure can be applied to real molecules , and what is the driving force that prevent a different type of LCAOs when the molecule is vibrating.

You are aware of the Born-Oppenheimer approximation?

@IanBush Yes, but I don't know how it is related to this question.

Generally vibrational energy is small wrt. the electronic energy so a good approximation can be made that the atoms are at their equilibrium positions. You will need an expert to answer your question when this break down.

I recall that it is common to treat the distorsions due to thermal fluctuations (vibrational modes) as small perturbations of the electronic ground state of proper simmetry. This is the motivation for some Transitions to be observed in UV-vis spectra of octahedral complexes even though they should be simmetry forbidden.

Also molecular vibrations are, generally, accounted in Group-Theoretical treatments of molecular systems: see Cotton's Textbook or: https://vallance.chem.ox.ac.uk/pdfs/SymmetryLectureNotes.pdf
